# Possible to get chained value of DynamicObject?

Tags: c#, dynamic

Creating a class that implements DynamicObject

```
public class Test : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (binder.Name == ("Posts"))
        {
            result = "property accessed was 'Posts'";
            return true;   
        }

        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }
}
```

I can call

```
dynamic test = new Test();
var result = test.Posts;
```

And the value of `result` is "dynamic test = new Test();
var result = test.Posts;"

That's fine.

What I'm wondering is, when TryGetMember is invoked is it possible to get the chained value.

So if I called:

```
dynamic test = new Test();
var result = test.Posts.Load(123);
```

I can then do something like:

```
if (binder.Name == ("Posts"))
{
    if (... == "Load")
        result = this.Load<Post>(... 123);
    return true;   
}
```

Is something like that possible? I can't figure out a way to do it.

So far I have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic test = new Test();
        dynamic result = test.Posts.Load(123);

        Console.WriteLine(result.Name);

        dynamic result2 = test.Posts.Load(909);

        Console.WriteLine(result2.Name);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Test : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (binder.Name == ("Posts"))
        {
            result = new ChainBuilder(this, "Post");
            return true;   
        }

        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }

    public T Load<T>(int id) where T : Post, new()
    {
        if (id == 123)
            return new T {Id = 123, Name = "Bananas"};

        return new T {Id = 0, Name = "Others"};
    }

    private class ChainBuilder : DynamicObject
    {
        public dynamic OriginalObject { get; set; }
        public string PropertyInvoked { get; set; }

        public ChainBuilder(DynamicObject originalObject, string propertyInvoked)
        {
            OriginalObject = originalObject;
            PropertyInvoked = propertyInvoked;
        }

        public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
        {
            if (binder.Name == "Load")
            {
                result = OriginalObject.Load<Post>((int)args[0]);
                return true;
            }

            return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
        }
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which is thanks to Bartosz.

But looks like it's basically what Marc has supplied.

Give's me a good starting point! I'll leave this open for now for any other suggestions.

This question has resulted in

- https://gist.github.com/3798206
- https://github.com/phillip-haydon/Raven.DynamicSession

Not a real project, just prototyping but achieved what we wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each step of the evaluation is separate; it does not evaluate `.Posts.Load(123)` - it evaluates `.Posts`, and then separately evaluates `.Load(123)`, so no: you can't do this in one step. The trick is to compose the values yourself, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Text;
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        dynamic test = new Test();
        var result = test.Posts.Foo.Bar(123, "abc");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
public class Test : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder,
        out object result)
    {
        result = new MemberAccessWrapper("member accessed was " + binder.Name);
        return true;
    }
    private class MemberAccessWrapper : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly string message;
        public override bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args,
            out object result)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(message).Append("(");
            for(int i = 0 ; i < args.Length ; i++) {
                if(i!=0)builder.Append(", ");
                if (args[i] == null) {
                    builder.Append("null");
                } else if (args[i] is string) {
                    builder.Append("@\"").Append(((string)args[i])
                         .Replace("\"", "\"\"")).Append("\"");
                } else {
                    builder.Append(args[i]);
                }
            }
            builder.Append(")");
            result = new MemberAccessWrapper(builder.ToString());
            return true;
        }
        public MemberAccessWrapper(string message)
        {
            this.message = message;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return message;
        }
        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder,
            out object result)
        {
            result = new MemberAccessWrapper(message + "." + binder.Name);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I was just editing my post while you posted yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do it this way by implementing the basic dynamic interfaces instead of 'DynamicObject', but the most simple way is for your dynamic invocation of 'Posts' to just return another DynamicObject which will handle 'Load' method.